# kubernetes cluster secure entry point for api

Tags: node.js, ssl, kubernetes, token, google-cloud-endpoints

I built a kubernetes cluster witch contain a ui app, worker, mongo, MySQL, elasticsearch and exposes  2 routs with ingress and there is also an ssl certificate on top of the cluster static ip. Utilizing pub/sub and storage.
All looks fine. 
Now I’m looking for a secure way to expose 
An endpoint to an external service
Use case:
A remote app wishes to access my cloud app with a video guid in the payload in a secure manner and get a url to a video in the bucket

I looked at google endpoints service but couldn’t get it to work with kubernetes.

There is more services that will need an access point to the app.

What is the best way for me to solve this problem.

Comment: If you are in Google Cloud, your best option is cerate a service of type LoadBalancer https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/create-external-load-balancer/

Comment: thanks for replying. i don't see any authentication focus it this article.
i know today how to expose an endpoint from my ingress but not to secure it

Comment: Oh OK, I didn't know you were looking for an authentication system. Then a good approach is to deploy an ingress controller. Checkout https://docs.traefik.io/user-guide/kubernetes/ or https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx

Comment: Did you try [the tutorial for GCP endpoints with k8s](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/openapi/get-started-kubernetes-engine)?

Comment: @Jofre Could you post the comment as an answer, please?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. i solved it by simply adding the endpoint to the ingress controlling the app and protected it with SSL and JWT

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solve it by simply adding an endpoint to the ingress controlling the app, and protect it with SSL and JWT. Use this and this guides to add the ingress controller.

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/openapi/get-started-kubernetes-engine) tutorial shows how to integrate Kubernetes with Google Cloud Endpoint